# API Issues with DocuSign personal signature

Tags: docusignapi

we use Personal_Signature_PSM_Client to send documents for signing.

We have an error:

Caused by: com.keynectis.sequoia.client.exceptions.connector.IllegalDataConnectorException: [OperationId=ZZAVSSCD-SERVID01-_-20200529155209-4BU8RPTJ8RAM5S22;AppId=ZZAVSSCD;ServId=SERVID01] Operation request signature validation failed : No filter match signing certificate DN (CN=PA2-DEMO-Presales-s,OU=FOR TEST PURPOSES ONLY,OU=PSM Connector Signature,OU=FOR TEST PURPOSES ONLY,O=Docusign,C=FR)

Our test certificates are still valid.

psm-client-api-4.4.0.1.jar
psm-client-connector-4.4.0.1.jar are the libraries we use to connect

Comment: so you are using an oracle connector, does it have DocuSign functionality? do you have the documentation by Oracle? the issue doesn't seem to be related to the DocuSign API directly, so it's hard to help. It appears maybe related to networking/certificates so you may need to get your IT department involved.

Comment: Did this work before?

Comment: @InbarGazit yes, it worked before, no changes from our side have been made. We have used OpenTrust documentation to create this integration, the application for connecting DocuSign and our mobile app is on Heroku

Comment: can you point me to the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

This error message says that the certificate you are using is not trusted on DocuSign side. It can be valid (not expired) but needs to be authorized to access a specific workspace.

Looking on our side looks like you contacted the support team and the issue is now resolved.
In this situation, what needs to be done is indeed to log on the support website to ask for a new one.

Be careful to choose the right product as this is relative to the Protect & Sign product (https://support.docusign.com/en/acct1login) this will route the ticket faster to the right team.